# How to use other Layout for page the _Layout.vbhtml in .net mvc 3 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor

I want to use a different layout for all the Views in one folder. It's all my `Panel` views controlled by `PanelController.vb`

```
Function LogIn() As ActionResult
    Return View()
End Function
```

Currently all the views in my project utilize `_Layout.vbhtml` for the layout etc.

**How can I make these specific pages utilize e.g. `_PanelLayout.vbhtml` instead of the default?**

See below of what files I am talking about:

[image: Screenshot]

I am using Visual Studio 2010, .NET MVC 3, Pages are Razor or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the view's layout file at the top of the view -

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index"
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PanelLayout.vbhtml"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The question specifically calls for vbhtml (or vb.net) page.  The accepted answer is for cshtml (C#) razor page.   The correct answer for vb.net is:

```
@CODE
Layout ="~/Views/Shared/_PanelLayout.vbhtml"
End Code
```